# Disable Navigation Swipe in Metro IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-metro

I am trying to disable the navigation swiping.
I don't want the webpage to go back or forward when the user swipes left or right.

I noticed we can set the touch-action to none on the html element preventing the behavior.
However, when scrolling a child element that has some overflow, it will "chain" the scroll then will allow the back navigation.

So I thought of adding -ms-scroll-chaining: none on the html element, but it works only if the element scrolls.
So adding overflow: scroll on html actually does the trick. But now I have scrollbars showing on my other browsers.

What is the right way to do this?

```
    html {
        -ms-touch-action: none; /* Doesn't work if scrolling from child element */
        -ms-scroll-chaining: none; /* Works only with the next line */
        overflow: scroll; /* With this line all the other browsers have a scrollbar */
    }
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to take control of peoples browsers and try and disable specific features. Especially one's like navigation and history. But I can tell you that you could look into HTML5's history API's in javascript and detect the navigation event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    // Windows 8+ IE only
    html {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        -ms-touch-action: none; 
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -ms-scroll-chaining: none; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
body, html {
   -ms-touch-action:none;
}
```

and for every class which can be scrolled (Y - axis) apply

`-ms-scroll-chaining: none;`

In my project we have special class for scrolling what is comfortable:

```
.scroll-y {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
}
```

Worked for me

Comment: That is too constraining. I still want -ms-scroll-chaining to work on my elements. Chaining is good and important on a website.